# Can't build project - libswiftAVFoundation.dylib: errSecInternalComponent error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Suddenly I can't build project.
I got this error upon building :

> Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib
>   /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign'
>   'E5DD0B9344567811AABBF46F5AA802C26FAD6696' '--verbose'
>   '/Users/vlad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aohzmfeceiyidabrejtgjtlfukvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'
>   /Users/vlad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aohzmfeceiyidabrejtgjtlfukvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib:
>   errSecInternalComponent error: Task failed with exit 1 signal 0 {
>     /usr/bin/codesign '--force' '--sign'
>   'E5DD0B9344567811AABBF46F5AA802C26FAD6696' '--verbose'
>   '/Users/vlad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aohzmfeceiyidabrejtgjtlfukvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Frameworks/libswiftAVFoundation.dylib'
>   }

I tried to re-include Swift libraries but it didn't help.
This happened after I tried to connect to Firebase but then erased it from the pod file.

Anyone can tell me where the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: The error you have is generally related to a problem with codesigning. You could try `security unlock-keychain /Users/$USER/Library/Keychains/login.keychain` and/or make sure you have the right certificates selected for codesigning.

Comment: @l'L'l thanks for the guidance , I'll try it

Comment: @l'L'l everything is ok with certificates

Answer (score 0):

Clean (shift + cmd + k)

Delete Derived data (click file -> workplace settings -> click the arrow under derived data and delete the entire folder)

Clean again

Rebuild